# Switch Android pegando Varialvel

Tags: android, switch

Tenho um componente Switch e gostaria de pegar o status dele se esta on ou off. Ao procurar na net os exemplos que consegui não funcionou porem um deu certo porem ele só pega o valor quando eu faço a alteração de on/off por causa da função **setOnCheckedChangeListener**

Gostaria de saber um jeito de pegar o valor.

***O Entrega seria o meu Switch.***

```
 Entrega.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(Entrega.isChecked()){
                StatusEntrega = "Receber na Mesa";
            }else{
                StatusEntrega = "Receber no Balcão";
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Evite usar nome de variáveis com letra maiúscula

Comment: Por favor, marcar como certa a resposta caso tenha te ajudado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o `Entrega.isChecked()`, que retorna um `boolean` com o valor do Switch.